# Extract data from RallyDev and present them on a screen

Tags: rally

I am currently inverstigating some solution on how to extract data from RallyDev and present the data on a big screen in the office for the organization. The information I would like to display is "burndown chart pr. team" (we have 5 SCRUM teams); Top 5 tasks in progress by the indiviual teams and the iteration status ex "7 days remaning in the sprint (22/07/2013 to 02/08/2013).

We have presentation tool for our big sceens called "beats" which can display pictures from a network folder and the images are changed every 7 secound. The idea is to create a image with the information descriped above in one slide(image) pr. team.

My question is now have these images can be created, does any of you know or have expirences with a solution like this? or any recommendation for me:)

So far I have played around with Ruby to extract data into excel and created a macro in excel which created the burndown chart and list the tasks and the iteration status. But it's more at static solution, where have to do stuff manual every day. I was more looking for an automated solution with a windows schduler or somethink else.

Let me know if you have any thoughts on a solution and thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

You may explore writing apps using Rally App SDKs. There are two SDKs: the older AppSDK 1 based on Dojo framework and the new AppSDK 2 based on ExtJS framework:

[Rally WS API documentation and object model](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/)

[Documentation on App SDK 1 and App SDK 2](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/app-sdk)

[How to run apps outside of Rally](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps-outside-rally)

[LoginKey functionality](https://prod.help.rallydev.com/loginkey) which predates AppSDK2. You may use it with AppSDK 1. It allows displaying Rally standard reports and custom apps outside of Rally without having to login. It uses encoded read-only (viewer) user credentials.

[Lookback API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/analytics/doc) allows to see what any work item or collection of work items looked like in the past. This is different from using WS API directly, which can provide you with the current state of objects, but does not have historical data. LBAPI works with AppSDK 2